# How to drag an image onto a div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to implement the following feature:
(1) Select an image on their desktop and drag it into a div.
(2) Retrieve the base64 data of said image.

Are there any good libraries for this, specifically? (Snippets also welcome)

I've looked at various JQuery libraries that offer drag & dropping, but most of them are designed for the specific task of server uploading and I haven't had success in re-purposing them to meet my narrow task.

Comment: even if they are intended for upload, why can't you just use the drop event to do what you need?

Comment: @charlietfl didn't know about it! (web front-end is not my area of expertise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 has it's own `drop` event. You can use that event to process the file like `$('element').on('drop',someFunction);`. [Check this jsFiddle out](http://jsfiddle.net/calexblock/NGAKS/) to get a proper idea of how this works. You can use that to your necessities by following how it works.

Disclaimer: The code is not mine.
More on the drop event: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop), [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)